# goroutine leak with context timeout?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

In the code below, a client is putting a string on a service's input channel and listening for a reply on either an output or an error channel.

The context is set with a 5ms timeout.

```
func (s service) run() {
    <-s.input

    go func() {
        select {
        case <-s.ctx.Done():
            s.errs <- errors.New("ctx done")
            return
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    s.output <- 42
    fmt.Println("run exit")
}
```

The code times out correctly (due to the 10ms sleep) and outputs

```
error:  ctx done
```

However, the "run exit" is never printed.

**Question**: Is there a goroutine leak with processes stuck on

```
s.output <- 42
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/S1K9thh6Anx) example

Comment: If the goroutine is blocked on `s.output <- 42`, then it can't return. The point of `s.ctx.Done()` being a channel is so you can select against multiple cases.

Comment: Gotcha. What I am trying to figure out is how to get the client to give up and move on in the case of a timeout, without leaving the service hung up when it eventually gets around to putting something on the output channel.

Comment: `ctx.Done()` is a channel so you can select against multiple cases -- select between `s.output`, and the `cdx.Done()` channel. I don't understand why there's another goroutine involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Context has timeout of 5 milliseconds and you sleep for 10 millisecond before this line `s.output <-42` is run. So the context is timeout first and error occurs, that correct, but take a look at `main` function:

```
select {
    case o := <-s.output:
        fmt.Println("output: ", o)
    case err := <-s.errs:
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }
```

The `select` statement has reached case `err := <-s.errs` so it will break the select and go to the end of `main` function => program exit
Even if `s.output <- 42` is call simultaneously with `s.errs <- errors.New("ctx done")` only one case has reached in `select` statement, if you need to reach second case, put a loop around select statement